# starting a linux script in deamon mode and terminating when requried

Tags: linux, daemon

I need to start a linux script in a background in deamon mode and then kill it when requried.  To that end I try the following

`script.sh -daemon -p zpid`

What I'm confused about the above is,

- What is the `-daemon` flag, I assume this says to start the process as a daemon.  Is this the same as using `-d` ?
- What does the `-p zpid` part do ? I assume it assigns the processID to the `zpid` variable ?
- How do I kill the process?

Comment: It seems the `-d`is referred to as daemon but I am not sure about the `zpid`. As it was interesting for me I search a little bit and couldn't find any doc related to `zipid`. could you share the link where you find this solution? and by the way, you could use `screen` command or `tmux` to run the command in the background.

Comment: `zpid` is the name I gave to `-p` output.  I thought that would save the value of the processID in the `zpid` variable.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense, so you named the process then you can find it and kill it. so you should be able to find your process with this command `ps aux | grep -i zipid`

Answer (score 0):

The -d represent the daemon and the -p is for naming the process id then you can use that name to find the process and stop it with this command `ps aux | grep -i zipid`

But I think its better to use `screen` or `tmux` as you can also see the output as well.